# Use excel cell in SQL query string (function)

Tags: sql, excel

i want to import data from a mssql database into my excel spreadsheet. Everything works fine with parameters. But i want to use a cell value in a function query:

Example:

```
select ROUND(dbo.fn_geteffort(3484, 'Project', 0, 1)/8,2)
```

I want to use a cell value for 3484!

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You mean the value '3484' is in a cell and you want to include that in your query string?

Then:

```
s = "select ROUND(dbo.fn_geteffort(" & Sheet.Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber) & ", 'Project', 0, 1)/8,2)"
```

Or:

```
s = "select ROUND(dbo.fn_geteffort(" & Sheet.Range("A1").Value & ", 'Project', 0, 1)/8,2)"
```

Comment: My table name is "status" and the value is in cell D5 - can you please make an example on this infos... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your query with VBA scripting.

```
Worksheets("sheet_with_table").ListObjects(1).QueryTable.CommandText = "select ROUND(dbo.fn_geteffort(" & Worksheets("status").Range("D5").Value & ", 'Project', 0, 1)/8,2)"
```

If you want your query to update whenever you change status!D5, post following code in status worksheet event Change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("sheet_with_table").ListObjects(1).QueryTable.CommandText = "select ROUND(dbo.fn_geteffort(" & Worksheets("status").Range("D5").Value & ", 'Project', 0, 1)/8,2)"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your post! I use thq Excel Microsoft Query Tool - no VBA at the moment. it unclear for me, how can i use your informations...

Comment: you mean, i must use vba? Do you have time to give me a simple example to query a database from VBA-code... ;))))

Comment: Short introduction to VBA: On Excel: Alt+F11 >> Double click the status worksheet on left tree, something like "Sheet4 (Status)">> paste code from answer, replacing sheet_with_table with the name of data worksheet. And voila, it should be working!

Comment: You don't have to do all work in VBA. You can use your current worksheet, with your data and query. With VBA you will just change SQL command.

Comment: it doesn´t work. i tried the following:
1. data - another data sources - ms query
2. insert the sql query "select ROUND(dbo.fn_geteffort(" & Sheet.Range("A1").Value & ", 'Project', 0, 1)/8,2)"
3. Insert your VB code. 
any idea?

Comment: You should start with a valid SQL statement. Can you send a sample file?